# Learning PHP : Trying to add a new database with CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS // Got an error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] base unknow

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

following a tutorial to set up my first PHP blog I encounter a problem.
I have a db.sql file containing the following code : `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS`blog`DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`that should create the database named blog.

I have two others files at the directory root, namely 'database.php' and 'home.php'

In the file Database.php I try the following method `$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog;charset=utf8', 'root', '');`

When I test my file with my browser and phpMyadmin I catch the following error message : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] database 'blog' unknow.

Why so ? As for ressources I'm using Wamp and phpMyadmin.

Comment: Have you executed the sql file?

Comment: I think so, in my home.php file I have this : ` $db = new Database(); echo $db->getConnection();` is that correct ?

Comment: I think not that the Database constructor execute the sql file. use `mysql -u root <db.sql` on commandline